# For loop not printing last vector value in C++

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, vector

I'm just learning C++ classes and was trying to compare and sort vector values (which time is earlier than the other), and while everything else works, my last value in the vector does not get printed. I'm guessing it has something to do with the for loop in my main function but I can't figure it out by myself.

Thanks for any help!

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Please enter hour, minute, second: ";
    int hour, minute, second;
    std::cin >> hour >> minute >> second;
    Time now(hour, minute, second);
        //random time values
    Time now1(13,1,45);
    Time now2(23,47,12);
    Time now3(1,8,8);
    Time now4(19,4,13);

    std::vector<Time> times;
    times.push_back(now1);
    times.push_back(now);
    times.push_back(now2);
    times.push_back(now3);
    times.push_back(now4);
    sort(times.begin(), times.end(), IsEarlierThan);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++){
        //std::cout << times[i] << std::endl;
        times[i].PrintAmPm();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Time.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Time.h"

Time::Time() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
}

Time::Time(int theHour, int theMinute, int theSecond){
    hour = theHour;
    minute = theMinute;
    second = theSecond;
}

int Time::getHour() const {
    return hour;
}

int Time::getMinute() const {
    return minute;
}

int Time::getSecond() const{
    return second;
}

void Time::PrintAmPm() const {
    int hour1;
    std::string amOrPm;
    if ((hour >= 0) && (hour <= 11))
        amOrPm = "am";
    else
        amOrPm = "pm";

    if ((hour > 12) && (hour <= 23))
        hour1 = hour - 12;
    if (hour == 0)
        hour1 = hour + 12;
    if ((hour > 0) && (hour <= 12))
        hour1 = hour;

    if ((minute < 10) && (second >=10))
        std::cout << hour1 << ":0" << minute << ":" << second << amOrPm << std::endl;
    if ((minute < 10) && (second < 10))
         std::cout << hour1 << ":0" << minute << ":0" << second << amOrPm << std::endl;
    if ((minute >= 10) && (second < 10))
        std::cout << hour1 << ":" << minute << ":0" << second << amOrPm << std::endl;
}

bool IsEarlierThan(const Time& t1, const Time& t2){
    if (t1.getHour() < t2.getHour())
        return true;
    if ((t1.getHour() == t2.getHour()) && (t1.getMinute() < t2.getMinute()))
        return true;
    if ((t1.getHour() == t2.getHour()) && (t1.getMinute() == t2.getMinute()) 
            && (t1.getSecond() < t2.getSecond()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Time. h

```
class Time {
public:
    Time();
    Time(int theHour, int theMinute, int theSecond);

    int getHour() const;
    int getMinute() const;
    int getSecond() const;

    void PrintAmPm() const;

private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};

bool IsEarlierThan(const Time& t1, const Time& t2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not seeing one of your outputs because your tests never print when `minutes >= 10` and `second >= 10`.

```
if ((minute < 10) && (second >=10))
if ((minute < 10) && (second < 10))
if ((minute >= 10) && (second < 10))
// None of these handle minute >= 10 && second >= 10!
```

`now2` has two digit minutes and seconds, so your print method does nothing with it.

Really, the correct solution here is to replace these tests with a single use of `cout` that use [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) and [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to align your outputs without needing to manually/conditionally zero pad.

```
    std::cout << std::setfill('0')
              << hour1 << ':'
              << std::setw(2) << minute << ':'
              << std::setw(2) << second << amOrPm << std::endl;
```

No need for checking the ranges for `minute`/`second`, you just unconditionally tell `cout` that padding should be done with `0`, and set a desired width to pad to (needs to be set each time because outputting a `char` resets the width).

Comment: I wouldn't call it *the* *correct* solution. It's *an easier* solution (and also correct), but the asker's approach is also correct and may be easier at their level of learning.

Comment: @immibis: The asker's approach is incredibly error-prone (as demonstrated by the very fact that they're having this problem). [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a guideline for a reason. It's too easy to end up writing the same code over and over with subtle errors that you don't run into because your various  code paths with errors just aren't hit. Even if the OP isn't ready for IO manipulators, violating DRY isn't helping them; at worst they could perform the manual string manipulations once for each value, rather than embedding it in 3-4 different output lines.

Comment: Point is, I generally consider "correct" to encompass not merely working, but maintainable and (easily) verifiable. Repeated copy and paste with small tweaks is the opposite of maintainable/verifiable; too easy to overlook something.

Comment: Indeed, however I don't like to discourage new programmers from doing things the obvious way, simply because otherwise they can feel overwhelmed with all the things people are telling them not to do. Once you've written and debugged the same code a few times *then* you can go "wow, it's so much easier to do it this way!" but until then it can feel like your creativity is being stifled. I don't want people to learn that they always have to do things "by the book", as it were. They can come to that conclusion themself.

Comment: I didn't know DRY - thank you for pointing me to it. I'm just starting out now and this was a data structures lecture assignment to help us better understand how classes work. Thank you for the help either way!